# Java Heap Error

Tags: java, generics, collections, cluster-computing, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to get the distance in a Map but I keep getting java heap error... I don't understand why even specially when the data is stored in a Map.

Here is my code:

```
Map<Integer, double[]> getDistanceTable(Map<String, Double[]> vectors) {
    Map<Integer, double[]> distance = new HashMap<>();  
    int size = vectors.keySet().size();
    for(int i=0; i<vectors.keySet().size(); i++) {
        double[] features = new double[size];
        int index = 1;
        features[0] = 0;
        for(int j = i+1; j<vectors.keySet().size(); j++) {                  
            features[index] =new QueryClustering().getDistance(vectors.get(i), vectors.get(j)); 
            index++;
        }
        distance.put(i, features);
        size--;
    }       
    return distance;

}
}
```

Comment: Maybe because new QueryClustering().getDistance returns a big object and you have too many instance of this type in the Map which cannot fit into the heap

Comment: Try not creating a new QueryClustering object on each iteration. Try to create it outside any 'for', and just call method getDistance(...) inside 'for' clause.

Comment: Please can you give more details, including the exact error message? One (unrelated) issue I can see is that you're doing `vectors.get(i)`. `i` is an `int` yet the key type of `vectors` is `String`.

Comment: your solution is of order O(n^2). You can use dynamic programming to reduce the complexity to O(n). That will use much lesser heap memory for this kind of problems.

Comment: What heap error you are getting?

Comment: @Raman Shrivastava, I think you are right, but could you please explain how can i do that? I mean a piece of code would be great..

Comment: @Adrián, what do u mean by that... I need to do it for each object at each iteration.. could you please be more specific?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto QueryClustering().getDistance returns a Double[] array, is that an issue??

Comment: @Adnan: Yes, I will copy and modify your code and put it as a possible answer.

Comment: @Adnan what is the size of the array and how many entries do you have in vectors?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this modification:

```
Map<Integer, double[]> getDistanceTable(Map<String, Double[]> vectors) {

    // Define it once, call it multiple times inside 'for' clause:
    QueryClustering queryClustering = new QueryClustering();

    Map<Integer, double[]> distance = new HashMap<>();  
    int size = vectors.keySet().size();
    for(int i=0; i<vectors.keySet().size(); i++) {
        double[] features = new double[size];
        int index = 1;
        features[0] = 0;
        for(int j = i+1; j<vectors.keySet().size(); j++) {                  
            features[index] = queryClustering.getDistance(vectors.get(i), vectors.get(j)); 
            index++;
        }
        distance.put(i, features);
        size--;
    }       
    return distance;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but still the error stays, didn't change anything :(

Comment: @Nicolas Filotto There are more than 100,000 keys. Each key has a Double[] with 16 values in it

Comment: @Adnan: We shall continue improving code. Please try replacing Integer on map, to int. Like this:
    Map<int, double[]> distance = new HashMap<int, double[]>();
Also please keep latest improvement (QueryClustering creation outside 'for' clause).

Comment: Thanks buddy for the concern, but I just solved the problem, you won't believe it what the hell was.... basically my JVM was spending much more time on garbage collection.... so only a simple change has made my code to work :)   P.S. I just moved double[] outside of the loop and then it worked

Comment: Are you sure it is ok to do that? If you move out 'features' array, it won't create a new one on each iteration. So all distances will have same 'features' array.

Comment: Another big lesson about programming in java... thanks!